# Google App Engine, Datastore and Task Queues, Performance Bottlenecks?

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, rest, google-cloud-datastore

We're designing a system that will take thousands of rows at a time and send them via JSON to a REST API built on Google App Engine. Typically 3-300KB of data but let's say in extreme cases a few MB.

The REST API app will then adapt this data to models on the server and save them to the Datastore. Are we likely to (eventually if not immediately) encounter any performance bottlenecks here with Google App Engine, whether it's working with that many models or saving so many rows of data at a time to the datastore?

The client does a GET to get thousands of records, then a PUT with thousands of records. Is there any reason for this to take more than a few seconds, and necessitate the need for a  Task queues API?

Answer (score 2):

The only bottleneck in App Engine (apart from the single entity group limitation) is how many entities you can process in a single thread on a single instance. This number depends on your use case and the quality of your code. Once you reach a limit, you can (a) use a more powerful instance, (b) use multi-threading and/or (c) add more instances to scale up your processing capacity to any level you desire.

Task API is a very useful tool for large data loads. It allows you to split your job into a large number of smaller tasks, set the desired processing rate, and let App Engine automatically adjust the number of instances to meet that rate. Another option is a [MapReduce API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/).

Comment: What I don't understand is why we're hitting the limit so easily. 1MB of data taking 30 seconds to save doesn't make sense. Is this design limitation for scalability? I can save 1MB of data to a SQL database in a fraction of a second.

Comment: How can we answer this question without looking at your code? Did you check where your code spends most of this time? If I have to guess, you are saving entities one by one and use non-asynchronous put calls.

Comment: correct. We're now using async put calls, which helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really good question, one that I've been asked in interviews, seen pop up in a lot of different situations as well. Your system essentially consists of two things:

1. Savings (or writing) models to the data store
2. Reading from the data store.

From my experience of this problem, when you view these two things differently you're able to come up with solid solutions to both. I typically use a cache, such as memcachd, in order to keep data easily accessible for reading. At the same time, for writing, I try to have a main db and a few slave instances as well. All the writes will go to the slave instances (thereby not locking up the main db for reads that sync to the cache), and the writes to the slave db's can be distributed in a round robin approach there by ensuring that your insert statements are not skewed by any of the model's attributes having a high occurance.